# How do companies decide what anime to dub?

Tags: anime-production

How do companies decide what anime to dub? Just curious how dubbing companies decide which anime they should dub. Do they decide base on popularity or some other factor?

Comment: [The answer to "Why is dubbed anime commercially considered a 'premium'?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/30402/2516) touches the reason in a brief.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is dubbed anime commercially considered a "premium"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30384/why-is-dubbed-anime-commercially-considered-a-premium)

Answer (score 1):

They choose based off the potential to make money.  If the topic is relevant enough for an overseas audience they will dub it, otherwise they'll either choose to use subtitles or do nothing.

Usually that is why dubbed anime is anime that is already relatively well known/popular, as if it is popular, it can be franchised.