# What is the difference in cost for anime aired on TV and online anime?

Tags: anime-production

I want to know the difference between production cost of animes that aired on TV and anime that can only be found online.

How much more or less does it cost to produce anime online instead of on TV?

Comment: This can answer part of your question [How much does a typical anime series/episode cost](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4179/1458)

Comment: I can't imagine being online would make a difference in how much the show costs to write, draft, design, animate, or market, so any difference would have to be cost to broadcast vs cost to stream. According to [Logan's answer on the question Dimitri mx linked](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4179/7579), TV slots for a 52-episode series are in the ballpark of 50 million yen (around $439,000). I would imagine streaming episodes from your own servers for a year can't be too much cheaper than this; it might even be more expensive.

Comment: Usually services like Crunchyroll and Netflix pay you to stream your content, but that's for content that's already established in some other venue; I've never heard of a streaming company making a deal where another company pays them to run content. Usually they either pay media companies to run preexisting content or they pay a production company to create content for them.